# What data type does HWND type belong to?

Tags: ruby, windows, winapi

I'm trying to learn about the Win32api for Ruby, and I've come across the `HWND` type in different functions such as the [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) function. What does the `HWND` type do, and what data type does it belong to; pointer, integer, or long?

Comment: [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/windows-data-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HWND represents a window to the operating system and is an opaque pointer value. That is you may know the value of a particular HWND but you know nothing about the data backing that value.

Answer (score 0):

Handles refer to a resource that has been loaded into memory. This type is declared in WinNT.h as follows:

typedef PVOID HANDLE;

Best Regards,
Baron